# Is it possible to forward ports through SSH in this scenario?

Tags: ssh, port-forwarding

### Description

I have a PostgreSQL server across the internet in a laboratory network. Currently I'm using ssh to connect to it. However I would like to have an Adminer docker on my local network connected to the server. Is it possible to create a port redirect so the docker can connect to a port on my local computer that redirects me to the PostgreSQL service?

I believe this ssh command may work but not sure, I also would like a brief explanation of how it works:
`ssh -L 5000:myserverdomain:5432 postgresql@myserverdomain`

### Diagram

Small diagram that represents the scenario:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command you show will make port 5432 of myserverdomain available on port 5000 at the machine you're running the command on.

It should work, but (if I'm correct) since you're running the command on your host and not on a Docker container, by default the Adminer container won't be able to reach the port 5000 on the host machine (Docker containers running through a bridge network cannot reach ports of the host machine). So you can run the ssh command on a container ([I made one](https://github.com/David-Lor/Docker-SSH-Port-Forward-Client) that does ssh port forwarding), or just run the Adminer container with the network "host".

At last, you might want to use the modifier -N on the SSH command to avoid opening an interactive session, and just run the port forward. And you could even use autossh to reconnect if the connection drops.

Answer (score 0):

This initiates a connection to myserverdomain and forwards everything on localhost(which is myserverdomain again) port 5000 to port 5432 on myserverdomain (localhost).

So essentially You're forwarding traffic from localhost 5000 to localhost 5432

```
ssh -L 5000:myserverdomain:5432 postgresql@myserverdomain
```